# __unicode__ returned with FK information

Tags: django, django-models

I got this:

```
class CoworkersContractedPlans(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    coworker = models.ManyToManyField(Coworkers)
    service = models.ManyToManyField(Services)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status)

    class Meta:

        verbose_name = 'Contracted Plans'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Contracted Plans'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.coworker.first_name
```

Here I want to be returned the first name of the coworker, what is a foreign key. On my admin it comes as "(None)", but it is fulfilled.

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.coworker.first_name
```

Can some one help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Which Coworker name? Your relation is `ManyToMany`, so you have link to many coworkers.

You can try `return self.coworker.all()[0].first_name` to get first coworker's name.

Comment: lol... it was a "peopleware" problem. Of course it has to be FK, no m2m field. Think I should say sorry to bother ppl with this.